# Ways to speed up my bash script?

Tags: bash

Yet, i know its a lot faster than doing things by hand. But is there anyway to maybe speed up this script? Multi-thread or something? I'm new to unix and this is my first script =). Open for suggestions or any changes made. Script seems to pause a lot on a certain generated domain randomly.

```
#!/bin/bash
for domain in $(pwgen -1A0B 2 10000); 
do
      whois $domain.com | egrep -q '^No match|^NOT FOUND|^Not fo|AVAILABLE|^No Data   Fou|has not been regi|No entri'
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
              echo "$domain.com : available"
              else
              echo "$domain.com"
          fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before splitting and distribution,

**WARNING** This seem not to be useful: Asking `pwgen` to build 10'000 lines formed by `two` characters between `a` and `z`... Also there is only `echo $((26*26)) -> 676` possibilities (in fact, as `pwgen` try to build *speakable* words, there is only 625 possibilities).

```
pwgen -1A0B 2 10000 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail
 27 ju
 27 mu
 27 vs
 27 xt
 27 zx
 28 df
 28 sy
 28 zc
 29 dp
 29 zd
```

So with this command, you will do upto **29 times** same thing.

Trying 10x to run `pwgen -1A0B 2 10000` for printing how much different combinaison is proposed and which combinaison was proposed more time and less time:

```
for ((i=10;i--;)); do
    echo $(
        (
            (
                pwgen -1A0B 2 10000 |
                    sort |
                    uniq -c |
                    sort -n |
                    tee /dev/fd/6 |
                    wc -l >/dev/fd/7
            ) 6>&1 | (
                head -n1
                tail -n1
            )
        ) 7>&1
    )
  done
6 bd 625 31 bn
3 bj 625 29 sq
6 je 625 30 ey
4 ac 625 30 sz
5 ds 625 29 wf
4 xw 625 28 qb
4 jj 625 30 pa
6 io 625 29 sg
4 vw 625 30 kb
5 fz 625 31 os
```

this print:

```
|  |  |   |  |
|  |  |   |  \- max proposed pattern
|  |  |   \---- number of times max proposed pattern was issued
|  |  \-------- number of different differents purposes
|  \----------- min proposed pattern
\-------------- number of times min proposed pattern was issued
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with desired domain names first. Call this `domains.lst`:

```
pwgen -1A0B 2 10000 > domains.lst
```

Then create smaller files out of this:

```
split --lines=100 domains.lst domains.lst.
```

Then create a script which gets a file-name and processes that file using `whois`. Also creates an output file `input.out`.

Create another script that uses `&` to start the above script in the background for all small chunks. Merge the outputs after all background tasks finish.

Comment: How do I go about doing the input.out file exactly?

Comment: if the input file is `domain.lst.aa` then output file name will be `domain.lst.aa.out`. You can do `echo "$domain.com : available > $1.out"`